# Android App Links manual verification not working

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-12, android-app-links

I have an Android app whose `targetSdkVersion : 30` and App Links are working as expected on my device running Android OS 11, but they are broken (web links don't open the app by default) on another device running Android OS 12 because of [these](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#android-app-links-verification-changes) changes. I should go to OS level settings and manually add (see my app screenshot) the links to make them open the app.

[image: My App]

There are some apps, for example gmail, that has verified links by default (see gmail screenshot) and I was trying to achieve the same thing for my app as well by following Android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#manual-verification). However when I try to review the verification results, I don't see the expected output (see terminal screenshot). I have waited few minutes before reviewing the verification results but nothing yet. May be I'm missing something and I need some help. Thank you.

[image: Gmail]

[image: Terminal]

Comment: Any updates? I got the same

Comment: I think it's a timing issue because it started working for me automatically after a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I got same situation. I done all changes that needs to be done for android 12.

**BUT** I found that if you will upload not valid json to your.domain/.well-known/assetlinks.json the links wouldn't be verified until you will verify them manually. For my case it was json without one '}'.

you also can check this with tools->App Links Assistant->open digital asset links file generator->click button "Link and Verify"
you should get 2 green "ok":
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a debug version on the device running Android OS 12?

if so my bet is that you didn't upload a debug certificated sha256_cert_fingerprints to  your.domain/.well-known/assetlinks.json

you can easily test it by downloading your app from google play on the android 12 device and see if it auto verifies your links.